# How can I make use of the QGIS authentication manager in PyQGIS processing scripts?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, authentication

I have developped a set of QGIS processing scripts that rely on some background data stored in a postgreSQL database. During my development phase I had the database on my localost server and connected with hardcoded credentials in the QgsDataSourceUri connection. Now we have a common server and I want to enable my colleagues to use the scripts as well. I have migrated the database to the new server and each user who runs a script needs to authenticate with their own respective credentials. My first attempt to solve this is based on [this great answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/87052/135572) and works well so far:

```py
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
# assign this information before you query the QgsCredentials data store
uri.setConnection("HOST", "PORT", "DB_NAME", None, None)
connInfo = uri.connectionInfo()

(success, user, passwd) = QgsCredentials.instance().get(connInfo, None, None)

if success:
    uri.setPassword(passwd)
    uri.setUsername(user)
    uri.setDataSource("SCHEMA", "TABLE_NAME", "the_geom")
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "Layer", "postgres")
```

The drawback of this method is that the users need to enter their credentials each time they run a script, even when they have already authenticated themselves by entering their master password and already have access to the databases through the QGIS Explorer.

Is there a way to make use of the authentication manager in the processing scripts, so that the users only have to authenticate themselves once per session and not each time they run a script?

What security implications would this have?

I would be very greatful for any advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to the good PyQGIS documentation, I was finally able to come up with a recipe:

```py
host = "HOST"
dbname = "DB_NAME"
port = "PORT"

# Check whether there is already an authentication configuration
# for this connection
settings = QgsSettings()
settings.beginGroup('PostgreSQL/connections')
authcfg = None
for connectionName in settings.childGroups():
    if settings.value(f'{connectionName}/host') == host and \
    settings.value(f'{connectionName}/database') == dbname:
        authcfg = settings.value(f'{connectionName}/authcfg')
        break

# Only if there was no suitable authentication configuration found,
# ask for credentials. Else use the existing authConfigId. 
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
if authcfg is None:        
    uri.setConnection(host, port, dbname, None, None)
    connInfo = uri.connectionInfo()
    (success, user, passwd) = QgsCredentials.instance().get(connInfo, None, None)

    if success:
        uri.setPassword(passwd)
        uri.setUsername(user)
else:
    uri.setConnection(host, port, dbname, None, None, authConfigId=authcfg)

uri.setDataSource("SCHEMA", "TABLE_NAME", "THE_GEOM")
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "LAYER_NAME", 'postgres')
```