# Verify PostGIS connection, username and password

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis

I wrote the code below, but I need that the PostGIS connection to be verified, to be sure that the username and password are right.
I tried this: [How to access user credentials in database connection?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78625/how-to-access-user-credentials-in-database-connection/78858#78858)
 , but it didn't worked.

I am using QGIS 3.8.3

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection('LPOSTDES-CL2', '5432', 'ugpi', None, None)
connInfo = uri.connectionInfo()
(success ,user, passwd) = QgsCredentials.instance().get(connInfo, None, None)
if success:
    QgsCredentials.instance().put(connInfo, user, passwd)
uri.setConnection('LPOSTDES-CL2', '5432', 'ugpi', user, passwd)
```

Comment: Replace `(a, user, passwd)` with `(success, user, passwd)`, it works with me.

Comment: @J.Monticolo Thanks! Edited the post and tried again, but didn't work, because, if I enter an incorrect username or password, it doesn't return me back some error message. To see what the QGIS receive, type in the end: ``print(uri.connectionInfo())``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly verify this with QtSql, see the following Python3 code :

```py
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase

host = "LPOSTDES-CL2"
port = 5432
database = "ugpi"

db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")
db.setHostName(host)
db.setPort(port)
db.setDatabaseName(database)

(success, user, passwd) = QgsCredentials.instance().get(connInfo, None, None)
if success:
    db.setUserName(user)
    db.setPassword(passwd)

if db.open():
    print("Connection successful !")
else:
    print("Connection failed.")
```

Here I just copy the method without have `connInfo` and there is no really reason for use QgsCredentials here, just a dialog with two QLineEdit widgets will do the stuff.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly :)