# PyQGIS - Adding layer from PostGis database on QGIS interface

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis

I have the same problem, bellow my code if some one can help me please.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsDataSourceUri

def run_script(iface):
    uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
    uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "Base_test", "user", "****")
    uri.setDataSource("public", "mytable", "geom","")

    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "mytable", "user")
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```

When I run this code I haven't un error but i see nothing on my QGIS interface.

I'm using, QGIS 3.12.

---

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsDataSourceUri
from qgis.utils import *
import processing

def run_script(iface):
    uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
    uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "Base_test", "Nassim", "*****")
    uri.setDataSource("public", "BPE", "geom")

    layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "BPE", "Nassim")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

This is my code whith the solution given by @Vincent Bré, but it still doesn't work

Comment: You say that you "have the same problem" but the same problem as what?

Comment: Did you run `run_script(iface)`? It's because all the code you show us is only declaring the function but you need to call it to work

Comment: Sorry PolyGeo, I juste made un copy past from an other post, my problème it's: i can't display my layer on QGIS interface whene I load it from Postgis DB

Comment: I have a new problem now, this solution seems working but it bug my QGIS app and i need to restart it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a modification on layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "BPE", "") removing the user in this function, what stope the bug, I'm sure of my parameters because when I load the same table frome postgis using the interface all is ok. but whene I'm using Pyqgis it give me "unusing layer"

```
uriPG = QgsDataSourceUri()
uriPG.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "Base_test", "Nassim", "******")
uriPG.setDataSource("public", "CABLES", "geom")
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uriPG.uri(), "BPE",)
if not layer.isValid():
    print("Layer %s did not load" %layer.name())
```

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

bellow the picture of my result in the console and QGIS interface

it gives " an using layer"

[image]

Comment: I fixed my problem, I juste changed in 'code'layer = QgsVectorLayer(uriPG.uri(), "BPE","postgres") , I don't use my own user here.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `QgsProject` instead of `QgsMapLayerRegistry`.

To add a single layer, you can use the `addMapLayer` method.

You can use the following code:

```
uriPG = QgsDataSourceUri()
uriPG.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "database", "user", "password")
uriPG.setDataSource("schema", "name_table", "geometry_column")
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uriPG.uri(), "name_table_in_qgis", "user")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answser, it stil not working for me. I don't know why besacuse it's excatlty you code what I put whith the good parameters .in addition, it makes my QGIS buggy and you have to relaunch it

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: no  error message

Comment: My code works. You run it from the Python console in QGIS?
Make sure you check the name of your table, the geometry column

Comment: >>>exec(open('C:/Users/NASSIM~1.MOK/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpmv2m58vg.py'.encode('utf-8')).read())

Comment: Do you try outside a function?

Comment: it's exactly by using it outside of the function that it makes me bug QGIS. If you have any way to check if connexion is etablished I can maybe debug my problem.

Comment: For this part I can refer you to the following link https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/350457/verify-postgis-connection-username-and-password

Comment: Thank you Vincent

Comment: Vincent, when I type  layer in the console it gives me,  'code'(layer
<QgsMapLayer: 'BPE' (Invalid)>) and QGIS still bugs and need to be restarted. do you know what is realy the error?

Comment: You have this error when you execute the code written in your post? Check the name of your table, schema and geometry column

Comment: I made a  modification on layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "BPE", "") removing the user in this function, what stope the bug, I'm sure of my parameters because when I load the same table frome postgis using the interface all is ok. but xhene i'm using Pyqgis it give me "unusing layer".

Comment: I'm out of ideas, sorry

Comment: I fixed my problem, I juste changed in 'code'layer = QgsVectorLayer(uriPG.uri(), "BPE","postgres") , I don't use my own user here.